# How do I run a program in an older Java version?

Tags: windows, java

I have multiple versions of Java installed on my computer.
Java 7 Update 45
Java 7 Update 55

If I start a Cisco ASDM-IDM Launcher it opens by default using Java 7 Update 55.
However, for the program to load correctly, I want to open it using Java 7 Update 45.
I do not want to uninstall Java 7 Update 55, because I need this version for other programs.

How do I do this, are there parameters I can add when running the program?

Thanks and regards,

Glenn

Comment: You do understand if you have `Java 7 Update 45` installed then your vulerable to ALL Java exploits that have been fixed through Update 55 right?  **Are you sure the program does not work with only Update 55 installed because it should**

Comment: Thanks for your concern and I understand, however when trying to run in Update 55, I get an error saying "Unable to launch device manager from ....". Upon running it with Update 45 I get no error and it launches without any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the JNLP file from your Cisco device manually, put it on your system and then run it with the Java VM of your choice (using the "Open with..." option).

Comment: There is no 'open with' option. It just seems to be the javaw.exe application with a lot of parameters added to it: C:\Windows\System32\javaw.exe -Xms64m -Xmx512m -Dsun.swing.enableImprovedDragGesture=true -classpath lzma.jar;jploader.jar;asdm-launcher.jar;retroweaver-rt-2.0.jar com.cisco.launcher.Launcher

Comment: I'm not sure what happens on your system. When I open Cisco ASDM from the device's webpage it gives me a `.jnlp` file. This is an XML file describing the jars and metainformation regarding ASDM. I can open this file using webstart (javaws).

Comment: Oh I see, I had already installed the ASDM launcher on my desktop using the newest Java version, so that version is also the one that is used when running it.
After installing the program, I have a shortcut on my desktop that is the javaw.exe with parameters.
If I install it with another version of java the target of the shortcut is pointing to the other version.. and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I created an account because I spent a good 90+ minutes trying to figure this out and hopefully this will help someone resolve their issue quicker.  I followed what's above but kept getting "no valid program to open file" (asdm.jnlp) and no "open with" option.

- Win 7
- IE 11.0.9600.17358
- Cisco ASDM 6.2(3)
- Added internal router address to compatibility view settings in IE
- Added security exception to Java through control panel
- Right clicked asdm.jnlp file> Properties> Opens with "Change"> Browse to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\javaws.exe and use to run ASDM as a Java Web Start application.

dph