# Choose java version in Windows

Tags: windows, java, launcher

I have both Java 8 and Java 9 installed on my computer. When I run Java from Powershell it runs `c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java`, which in turn runs Java 9.

I'm also using eXistdb which doesn't work with Java 9, but rather requires Java 8. I start eXistdb with `java -jar start.jar`.

Is there a way to specify which version of Java I want, besides specifying the full Path of Java 8? Something like the Windows Python launcher?

Comment: Not exactly meeting your criterion, so not proposed as an answer, but I'd just create a batch file `java8.bat` that specifies the full path of Java 8 `c:\path\to\java8\java.exe %*`, and invoke eXistdb with `java8 -jar start.jar`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a program in an older Java version?](https://superuser.com/questions/747951/how-do-i-run-a-program-in-an-older-java-version)